# apache2 not starting automatically in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2, encryption, autostart

I have fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation with apache2. I have noticed apache2 is not starting at the boot. I have tried to enable it with `sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults`, but it still doesn't start with the system...

Restarting using services `sudo service apache2 start` works ok.

I have checked the apache2 log `less /var/log/apache2/error.log`, but it seems the system doesn't start it at the boot. Any idea how to enable autostart?

**HINT**: My home folder is encrypted, while some websites `DocumentRoot` are stored in my ~/Public folder. Thus, apache2 probably cannot start, because some encrypted folders are not mounted at boot. Is there a way of starting apache2 on login, or postponing its launch until my home filesystem is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

You can postpone apache to start by renaming the symlinks which were created by`update-rc.d apache2 defaults` - "defaults" mean that such symlinks were created for default runlevels set in /etc/init.d/apache2, so in `/etc/rc2.d, /etc/rc3.d, /etc/rc4.d, /etc/rc5.d` directories..

In each above directory, you will see something like "`S91apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2*`"
issue command `sudo mv S91apache2 S99apache2` in each above directory.

The biggest is the number, the later the script will be started - however, using S99 is the latest posssible time to start...

Comment: that's useful. and what does S91 or S99 mean? how can I check when is the encrypted filesystem mounted?

Comment: regarding S91 and S99 have a look at the UpstartHowto
here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto#What_order_are_initscripts_started_and_stopped_in.3F

Comment: I'm afraid your encrypted /home directory will be only mounted after you log on...

Comment: indeed, that's the case. then my next question, can apache start with some virtual hosts, and enable virtual host from my encrypted home after I login?

Answer (score 0):

With heavy adoption of systemd as system manager and init system for debian based distributions like ubuntu , we can now use systemctl commands to enable a service to start when booting

for example :

> sudo systemctl enable apache2